# How to apply the NSApplicationPresentationOptions to an application?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, fullscreen

I am trying to make the application startup in a presentation mode while disabling the Dock, Menubar, Processes Switching, etc. I set the variable for these settings, but now I don't know how to actually apply these settings to the application. This is the code I have so far:

```
let presOptions: NSApplicationPresentationOptions = [
        .HideDock                  ,   // Dock is entirely unavailable. Spotlight menu is disabled.
    //  .AutoHideMenuBar           ,   // Menu Bar appears when moused to.
    //  .DisableAppleMenu          ,   // All Apple menu items are disabled.
        .DisableProcessSwitching   ,   // Cmd+Tab UI is disabled. All Exposé functionality is also disabled.
        .DisableForceQuit          ,   // Cmd+Opt+Esc panel is disabled.
        .DisableSessionTermination ,   // PowerKey panel and Restart/Shut Down/Log Out are disabled.
        .DisableHideApplication    ,   // Application "Hide" menu item is disabled.
    //  .AutoHideToolbar           ,
        .FullScreen
]
```

I believe that the line after that is:

```
let optionsDictionary = [NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions: presOptions]
```

But after that I am completely lost. Thank you any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an `NSWindow` with an `NSViewController`, you can do something like this:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear() {
        let presentationOptions: NSApplicationPresentationOptions = [
                .HideDock                  ,   // Dock is entirely unavailable. Spotlight menu is disabled.
                .DisableProcessSwitching   ,   // Cmd+Tab UI is disabled. All Exposé functionality is also disabled.
                .DisableForceQuit          ,   // Cmd+Opt+Esc panel is disabled.
                .DisableSessionTermination ,   // PowerKey panel and Restart/Shut Down/Log Out are disabled.
                .DisableHideApplication    ,   // Application "Hide" menu item is disabled.
                .FullScreen
        ]

        if let screen = NSScreen.mainScreen() {
            view.enterFullScreenMode(screen,
                withOptions: [NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions:
                    NSNumber(unsignedLong: presentationOptions.rawValue)])
        }
    }
}
```

It is not entirely clear which one of `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` is the best place to do this. Visually there does not seem to be a difference.

Comment: Thank you I am making this for a game, so I am using SKScenes. I put the code into my GameScene.swift file to try it out anyway. It seems to work fine, but just in case I was wondering if something needed to be changed because it is in a SKScene instead. Thank again!

Comment: @grahamcracker1234 If this works for you then don't forget to up vote the answer and mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: I know I just wanted to double check that there was nothing I needed to change.

Answer (score 2):

Updated code from Stefan Arentz' answer for Swift 4.2

```
let presentationOptions: NSApplication.PresentationOptions = [
        .hideDock                  ,   // Dock is entirely unavailable. Spotlight menu is disabled.
        .disableProcessSwitching   ,   // Cmd+Tab UI is disabled. All Exposé functionality is also disabled.
        .disableForceQuit          ,   // Cmd+Opt+Esc panel is disabled.
        .disableSessionTermination ,   // PowerKey panel and Restart/Shut Down/Log Out are disabled.
        .disableHideApplication    ,   // Application "Hide" menu item is disabled.
        .fullScreen
    ]

view.enterFullScreenMode(screen, withOptions: [NSView.FullScreenModeOptionKey.fullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions:presentationOptions.rawValue])
```

In addition, for me it only works properly if I call it from `applicationDidBecomeActive`.